# Searching in grouped ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, observablecollection, xamarin.forms

### **Background**

I followed [this guide](http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping) to create a grouped `ListView` in `Xamarin.Forms`. Doing so, the following `Property` is given which is bound as the `ItemSource` of the `ListView`:

`DevicesGrouped = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Device>>(sorted);`

Everything works just fine, including the grouping functionality.

To search  (and thereby filter) the entries in the list, I have tried to implement [this pattern](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-searchbar-recipe/):

```
this.ItemsSource = DevicesGrouped
        .Where (x => x.Name.ToLower ()
        .Contains (filter.ToLower ()));
```

### **The issue**

The problem is, that I do not have access to the properties of the `Device` as the objects reside in `Groupings`. I can only access the `Key` of the `DevicesGrouped` which, in this case, is a `Manufacturer`, where I want to search for the `Name`. The problem in searching for the `Key` is also, that the `ListView` scrolls to the position of the `Key` and thus hides the elements in the `ListView` behind the grouping header.

My question is thus, how would one access the properties of the `ObservableCollection` which is Grouped?

I have tried keeping a List which I use when I filter, but doing so, the app crashes, since `Groupings` are enabled on the `ListView` itself.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer to my question, and will post it if others run into the same issue.

Simple do the following when filtering your Grouped ListView:

```
_groupedDeviceList.ItemsSource =
                DevicesGrouped.Where(o => o.Any(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())));
```

`_groupedDeviceList` is of course your own list.

Comment: im trying to do same but im getting crash "Cannot cast from source type to destination type.", in my SelecteTemplate function when i try to cast item var user = (User)item;

Comment: This is working, but if the filter word is matched with any group the whole group is displayed. But i need exact content not all the group.

Comment: Same here. I want to do the same as Ganeshgm7 and get the same as Omer Obaid.
It isn't working though it looks fair at first glance.